# sql developer .Erreur d'E/S: Got minus one from a read call

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to establish a new connection in SQL Developer , but I got this error message: ''Statut: échec -Echec du test: Erreur d'E/S: Got minus one from a read call''. Can you please help me solve this problem.

[image: orcl]

Comment: For future reference, if you're using Oracle SQL Developer you should tag your questions with `[oracle-sqldeveloper]` and not `[plsqldeveloper]`, which is a **different tool** from a third-party vendor.

Comment: That's usually a ssl configure issue...